# Obtain backtrace from httpd?

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora, segmentation-fault, gdb

In my `/var/log/httpd/error_log` in Fedora 19 I have several child segmentation faults recorded. How can I get a backtrace for these when they occur?

Comment: Are the suggestions at [Apache Debugging Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html) helpful?

Comment: @rickhg12hs It's stopped happening now - maybe due to new versions of some packages being installed by the OS.